# Im function won't distribute over a sum

Tags: map

When I take the imaginary part of a complex number times a function, I get the answer I was expecting,

```
Refine[Im[(1+I) Cos[x], Element[x,Reals]]
-> Cos[x]
```

but if I include a sum,

```
Refine[Im[(1 + I) Cos[x] + (1 + I) Sin[x]], Element[x, Reals]]
-> Im[(1 + I) Cos[x] + (1 + I) Sin[x]]
```

It seems that I have to move the Im function inside the sum by hand,

```
Refine[Map[Im, (1 + I) Cos[x] + (1 + I) Sin[x]], Element[x, Reals]]
-> Cos[x] + Sin[x]
```

Why is this?  I can't think of a situation when this is *not* the right thing to do.  I'm using version 9.0.0.0.

Comment: What is the question? Why doesn't Mathematica do this? Or how do we work round it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `ComplexExpand`

```
Refine[Im[(1 + I) Cos[x] + (1 + I) Sin[x]], Element[x, Reals]] // ComplexExpand
```

> Cos[x] + Sin[x]

or use `Simplify` instead of `Refine`:

```
Simplify[Im[(1 + I) Cos[x] + (1 + I) Sin[x]], Element[x, Reals]]
```

> Cos[x] + Sin[x]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm still wondering why Mathematica doesn't do this by default.  In other words, is there some situation in which doing the _Map_ above gives a wrong answer?

Comment: @RodneyPrice. It is probably because doing such transformations by default costs extra processor time, time which is then wasted because the result isn't final and further computations obviate the extra work